# How to find "default" method from an interface using java reflection?

Tags: reflection, java-8

I want to find if a method is a **"default method"** through java reflection.I have tried printing the methods of `java.lang.Iterable`.

**Code Snippet :**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class ReflectionTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class c = Iterable.class;

    for(Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods())
    {
        System.out.print(Modifier.toString(m.getModifiers()));
        System.out.println("  "+m.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

**Result :**

```
public abstract  iterator
public  spliterator
public  forEach
```

here , spliterator() and forEach() should have printed `default`.
Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Don’t rely on `Modifier.toString` in that way. In the past, the modifiers for classes, fields, and methods were given unique distinct values so you could interpret them without looking at the type of the entity owning the modifier like that method suggests.

But while Java evolved, more modifier bits were added and it wasn’t possible to hold that property. In particular, when passing the modifier bits of a method to `Modifier.toString` unmodified, you will get the following surprising behavior:

- a *bridge* method will be printed as `volatile`
- a *varargs* method will be printed as `transient`

Therefore you should filter the bits. Java 7 [introduced a method providing the right mask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#methodModifiers()) so that you could use `Modifier.toString(m.getModifiers()&Modifier.methodModifiers())`.

But this only works because the old Java keywords map to unique modifier bits and the newer modifier bits are not associated with keywords. With newer Java versions even this might be insufficient.

For the `default` keyword, it is even simpler: there is no modifier bit associated with the keyword. If a `public`, non-`abstract`, non-`static` method appears in an **`interface`**, it must be a `default` method. That’s how [`Method.isDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#isDefault--) determines whether a method is a `default` method. `Modifier.toString(…)` has no chance of knowing whether the declaring class is an `interface` and therefore will never print `default`.

Answer (score 5):

In recent versions of java8 updates , we have `isDefault()` in `java.lang.reflect.Method` class , which does the trick.
Modifying my previous code a bit yields the result.

**Code:**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class ReflectionTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class c = Iterable.class;

    for(Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods())
    {
        System.out.print(Modifier.toString(m.getModifiers()));
        System.out.println("  "+(m.isDefault()?"default ":"")+m.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
public abstract  iterator
public  default spliterator
public  default forEach
```

**Note:** I have tested this in jdk8 update 20